# this.c = this.b result in this.b being altered when operations are performed on this.c

Tags: javascript, object, this

Can someone explain me why in the following example, `this.b` is being altered whereas the update is made on `this.c`? And what should I do to prevent this behavior?

```js
var a = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.b = [];
        this.c = this.b;
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.js-update', a.update.bind(this));
        $('body').on('click', '.js-reset', a.reset.bind(this));
    },

    update: function() {
        this.c.push("d");
        console.log(this.b);
    },

    reset: function() {
        this.c = this.b;
        console.log(this.c);
    }
};

a.initialize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kygtxbrn/1/

Comment: Because after`this.c = this.b;` the `c` and `b` references to the same object.

Comment: Assigning an array to another variable does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: this.b is just a reference to the array, so this.c = this.b assigns the same reference to c, so you are always modifying the same array. Use this.c = this.b.slice() for example to get a clone of the array.